# Overview used payment for last 6 month

Tags: php, mysql, payment, payment-methods

I want a overview of used payment methods for the pas 6 month
i.e. 200 orders: 100 creditcard, 70 paypal, 30 bank transfer

Is there a handy way to get this kind of information in php, mysql or ....

Answer (score 1):

You did not define where the data should be retrieved/viewed: Should it be possible to generate a report for the admins in the backend or is a one time SQL query enough?

For the first: I've seen Mirasvit Advanced Reports has a lot of reports, and also a function to filter per payment time and limit the time period.

For the second: You can write a query that queries sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_payment.

Something like:

```
SELECT sales_flat_order_payment.method, COUNT(*)
FROM sales_flat_order
JOIN sales_flat_order_payment ON sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id
WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY sales_flat_order_payment.method
```